# discord bot only seeing itself with command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle
from random import choice

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
intents = discord.Intents.all()

@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def ruser(ctx):
    await ctx.send(choice(ctx.guild.members))
```

This is some code for a discord bot I'm working on. If you type ".ruser", it's supposed to send a message saying the user. The problem is that it is only returning the bots name, and not any of the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't actually pass in the intents, you only declared the variable. You're supposed to add them to your bot as well.

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry if this was a simple question I am very new to python.